# How to compare data in the same table to find differences in one column, then group and sort them

Tags: sql

EDIT: I added some clarification at the bottom.

I have a very large order database with millions of records. What I'm trying to do is find out when the "Customer_Due_Date" column was changed. I track changes via the "onDate" field. I thought of selecting the table twice and doing a where clause but its not providing me the output I need:

```
Select

A.onDate AS Date1,
A.Order_No AS Order_No1,
A.Line_No AS LN1,
A.Customer_Due_Date AS Due_Date1,
B.onDate AS Date2,
B.Order_No AS Order_No2,
B.Line_No AS LN1,
B.Customer_Due_Date AS Due_Date2,
Count(DISTINCT A.Customer_Due_Date) as Count

FROM view_Bup_Backlog A (nolock), view_Bup_Backlog B (nolock)

WHERE A.onDate >= '2023-06-15'AND A.ERP_Id = 21
AND B.onDate >= '2023-06-15'AND B.ERP_Id = 21
AND A.Release_Key = B.Release_Key
AND A.Customer_Due_Date <> B.Customer_Due_Date

GROUP BY A.onDate, A.Order_No, A.Line_No, A.Customer_Due_Date, B.onDate, B.Order_No, B.Line_No, B.Customer_Due_Date
```

This is providing too much data back. As you can see from the sample below, It's giving me every record that doesnt match:

[Output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqNmw.png)

The abover is a sample output for a single order. While yes from the original order date of 6/15, all those records don't match and the Due Date was changed. What output I'm really seeking is to see just a list of Dates where it was changed and the before and after value. So for the above, I should see only 2 records as the Due Date changed only twice.

Can anyone assist?

EDIT: Some clarification. I have a large database of customer orders where people are editing the CUSTOMER_DUE_DATE. Every time any data is edited, a new record is created with the same key but different "onDate". I'm wanting to get a list showing for each order when the customer due data column was changed and the date it was changed. Right now I'm getting a list of all the dates that conflict. For example, in the screenshot I posted, I am getting 9 results for order number 11015630 even though the Due Date only changed twice (once from 6/16 to 6/23 and 6/23 to 8/31).

I want my output to simply read "Original Due Date: 2023-06-15. New Due Date: 6/23. Changed on: 6/17 (the onDate)." And repeat that for each time the date was changed. For the example I gavce in the attached screenshot, there should be two records of due data changes. The sql I have now is returning 9 results (see screen), simply provided me all the times it was different. I'm looking specifically for when that field was changed and to spit out the before and after for each contract.

Sample Data:

| Date | Order No | Line Item | Customer Due Date | Release Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-15 | 11015630 | 1 | 2023-06-16 | 1 |
| 2023-06-17 | 11015630 | 1 | 2023-06-23 | 1 |
| 2023-06-17 | 11015630 | 1 | 2023-06-23 | 1 |
| 2023-06-18 | 11015630 | 1 | 2023-06-23 | 1 |
| 2023-06-19 | 11015630 | 1 | 2023-06-23 | 1 |
| 2023-06-21 | 11015630 | 1 | 2023-06-23 | 1 |
| 2023-06-22 | 11015630 | 1 | 2023-06-23 | 1 |
| 2023-06-24 | 11015630 | 1 | 2023-06-31 | 1 |
| 2023-06-25 | 11015630 | 1 | 2023-06-31 | 1 |

There are multiple changes (non due date related). I am trying to capture only the times the due date was changed:

Desired Output:

| Date Changed | Order No | Line Item | Old Due Date | New Due Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-17 | 11015630 | 1 | 2023-06-16 | 2023-06-23 |
| 2023-06-17 | 11015630 | 1 | 2023-06-24 | 2023-06-31 |

Comment: [Bad SQL habbits you need to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Can you share some sample data and expected result?

Comment: Hello @PauloFernando . I'm wanting to get a list showing for each order when the due data column was changed and the date it was changed. Right now Im getting a list of all the dates that conflict. For example, editing the Output example in my original post, I would want to see this:

Date (date of edit): 2023-06-24       
Old Due Date: 2023-06-16
New Due Date: 2023-08/31
And then repeat that for every customer due date change. Right now its just spitting out all instances of it not matching. So they made other changed (non due date) it creates a new entry.

Comment: Please don’t link to images or add relevant information in comments (edit your question instead). Please update your question to show, as editable text, sample data for the table, the result you want to achieve (based on the sample data) and a simple explanation of how the result is achieved

Comment: You've grouped by every column, so the group by effectively does nothing. This might be a job for lead/lag, but it's hard to tell what you're trying to do. Could you provide some sample input and output, please? A description is hard open to misunderstanding, please show us actual rows.

Comment: @Schwern Post updated/edited.

Comment: @NickW Post updated/Edited.

Comment: @DevinAuspland you haven’t updated your question with what I requested i my previous comment

Comment: @NickW I added sample data and sample output in an editable table.

Comment: @DevinAuspland Could you show what happens if line item and release key change?

Comment: @DevinAuspland Should the second row have a Date Changed of 2023-06-24?

Comment: @DevinAuspland There is no 2023-06-31. June has 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need?

```
WITH VW AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  [Order No], [Customer Due Date] ORDER BY [Order No],[Date]) RN,
       LAG([Customer Due Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Order No] ORDER BY [Date]) AS [Old Due Date],
       *
FROM [tableName]
)
SELECT Date AS [Date Changed],
       [Order No],
       [Line Item],
       [Old Due Date],
       [Customer Due Date] AS [New Due Date]
FROM VW 
WHERE RN = 1
AND [Old Due Date] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [Order No], [Date]
```

Fiddle that I used to test:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4ec69/1

Comment: That is what I need but the release key doesnt change. Every order has a single release key. Trying to make those changes seemed to have messed with your code for me. I added a sample data set to my original question.

Comment: Edited the answer, check it out

Comment: Had to do a minor edit or 2 and add some more rows but this worked perfectly! Thank you.